Нужны ли маркеры пропуска слова, строфы, части предложения при цитировании поэтического текста, если он дается с сохранением деления на строки?
Нужны ли маркеры пропуска слова, строфы, части предложения при цитировании поэтического текста, если он дается с сохранением деления на строки? Как при этом дать ссылку на источник формата [2].
Пример (до и после приведенных строк есть строфы + в 3-й строке после "перо" в оригинале стоит еще одно предложение).

«Злых языков терпя тупые обличенья,
Я стал писать стихи, нужда рукой своей
Вручила мне перо» [3].

